# NavigationSplitView run time error when collapse and expand Sections

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationsplitview

The code I test is the following.

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

let dataSourceSection1 = [Folder(id: 1, name: "Folder1"), Folder(id: 2, name: "Folder2")]
let dataSourceSection2 = [Folder(id: 3, name: "Folde3"), Folder(id: 4, name: "Folder4")]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var columnVisibility = NavigationSplitViewVisibility.all
    @State private var folderIdSelected: Folder.ID?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            
            List(selection: $folderIdSelected) {
                
                Section("Section1") {
                    ForEach(dataSourceSection1) { folder in
                        Text("\(folder.id)")
                    }
                }
                Section("Section2") {
                    ForEach(dataSourceSection2) { folder in
                        Text("\(folder.id)")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            let values = dataSourceSection1 + dataSourceSection2
            if let folderId = folderIdSelected {
                let folderName = values.first(where: {$0.id == folderId})?.name ?? "no folder selected"
                Text("\(folderName) | \(folderId)")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Folder:

```
struct Folder: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

MyTestSplitViewApp:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyTestSplitViewApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

When run the code the following steps produces a crash:

1. Select Item(Folder) 3.
2. Back.
3. Collapse Section 2.
4. Select Item(Folder) 2
5. Back.
6. Collapse Section 1.
7. Expand Section 2.
8. Select Item(Folder) 4

Crash : `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1076f95f8)`

I try with different dataSource (Dictionary), surround Sections with NavigationView but don't solve the problem.